# A simple hashrate test in web browser

Tags: mining, hashrate, mining-hardware

I'm trying to make a webpage that when the user goes to the page and presses the test button it will calculate the current user's hardware hashrate and return the average hash rate for that hardware. I want to be able to give the user options of GPU and CPU.

I don't know how to test a CPU and GPU in a webpage to give them the results. I also don't know how to calculate a hashrate.

I'm not mining on the page this will be a hardware hashrate tester.

Answer (score 1):

Give [this](https://www.myseries.lima-city.de/code/miner.html) webpage a shot. It calculates your average Monero mining hashrate. You can adjust the used mining threads (for finding the best performance) and the how much your threads should be used (percent)... If you want to get your own widget for your webpage [this](http://www.coinhive.com) page could be interesting for you... (you can also let your users mine for you)

---

**Note 1**: To find your optimal mining threads you have to know your CPU cache. To mine Monero you need 2MB/thread.. If you have 4 threads and only 5MB CPU cache you should use 2 threads. If you have 8 threads and 20MB cache you should use all cores...

---

**Note 2**: You real hashrate depends on your algorithm and many other factors... The links I posted use the CryptoNight algorithm (used for Monero mining). SHA256D is the other algorithm but because you posted in the Monero q&a forum I provide these links for you! SHA256D is difficult to embed in webpages (haven't found any pages which provide GPU and RAM mining tests) because access to hardware like GPU and RAM with JavaScript is not that easy...

---

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464896/get-cpu-gpu-memory-information)

It shows you how to read out the GPU info with JavaScript. You can include that into your website. If you know what the visitor uses, you could use some API of a website to get informations about the average hashrate of that GPU or build your own database of informations you get from different websites and then search thru this database and return the average hashrate.

That way you don't need to actually try to hash something - which would be much more difficult.

But please do not forget that hashrate depends on what algorithm you use for mining. Meaning it depends on what you mine. That means you will need to include a choice for the visitor to choose the algo he wants to mine.